# Comparing pointers. Multiple inheritance issue?

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-inheritance

I am debugging some code. Execution has arrived to this method:

```
void EventNotifier::notify_observers(SpEventInfo pEvent, Observable* target)
{
    std::list<Observer*>::iterator it;
    for (it = m_observers.begin(); it != m_observers.end(); ++it)
    {
        Observable* observedTarget = (*it)->target();
        bool fNotify = (observedTarget == target);
        ...
```

The last sentence of previous excerpt has been executed. Both variables, observedTarget and target, have the same value but boolean fNotify is false! Involved 'target' objects are using multiple inheritance and 'Observable' is one of the parents. But everything is casted to Observable, so the comparison should be just pointers of same type. In fact, the debugger shows the same value for both pointers.

I have no idea of were is the problem. Any help is greately appreciated. Thank you

Cecilio Salmeron

Comment: Try using `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: How do you know that target and observedTarget are the same? Have you printed them out/looked at them in the debugger? Are the objects they point to the same or the actual pointers. The former doesn't mean the latter also holds.

Comment: try to print out their addresses, if they aren't the same then they aren't the same allocated object.

Comment: Do you want to compare the pointers or the `Observable` objects themselves?

Comment: @Paul RuberThe code is run in a unit test. I know that both objects are the same. The debugger shows that both pointers point to the same address.

Comment: The code is run in a unit test, so I know that both objects are the same. The debugger shows that both pointers point to the same address. But I printed the addresses and .. are different! I'd like to know if both pointers point to the same object. If both are casted to the same type, is there any difference between comparing the pointers or their content? Finally I found the problem: before invoking this method there was a wrong cast in C style, instead of a static_cast / dynamic_cast C++ style. Fixing this solved the problem. Thank you all for the tips and clues.

Answer (score 1):

> Both variables, observedTarget and target, have the same value but boolean fNotify is false!

You may like to check the code by adding a print statement:

```
printf("%p == %p is %d\n", observedTarget, target, int(fNotify));
```

> Involved 'target' objects are using multiple inheritance and 'Observable' is one of the parents.

If objects may derive from `Observable` more than once, then you may like to compare the addresses of the complete derived objects instead. `dynamic_cast<void*>(ptr)` returns the address of the complete derived object referenced by `ptr`, hence:

```
bool fNotify = dynamic_cast<void*>(observedTarget) == dynamic_cast<void*>(target);
```

Comment: I found the problem: before invoking this method there was a wrong cast in C style, instead of a static_cast / dynamic_cast C++ style. Fixing this solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you used the wrong kind of cast when you converted the pointers, either in the function parameter or the return value of `target()`, you could get a corrupted pointer. `dynamic_cast` is the best, and `static_cast` should be safe too. `reinterpret_cast` can cause problems, and an old C-style cast could be a `reinterpret_cast` depending on how it's used. If you didn't use an explicit cast then that should be OK too, the automatic conversions will always be safe.

It's surprising when you first discover that casting a pointer to a different type in the inheritance tree can change the pointer value.

Comment: Thank you. You were right. The problem was that before invoking this method there was a wrong cast in C style, instead of a static_cast / dynamic_cast C++ style. Fixing this solved the problem. Thank you